# Julia create an "Empty" Sparse Matrix comparable to R class ngCMatrix

Tags: r, matrix, julia, sparse-matrix

I am currently working on converting R code into Julia (0.6), and I was wondering if there was any Julia function that would allow me to create an object comparable to R sparse matrices of class ngCMatrix. They are very efficient since they just bear the location of non-zeros numbers without having to actually store a non-zero number.

```
sparseMatrix(1:10,1:10)
10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "ngCMatrix"

 [1,] | . . . . . . . . .
 [2,] . | . . . . . . . .
 [3,] . . | . . . . . . .
 [4,] . . . | . . . . . .
 [5,] . . . . | . . . . .
 [6,] . . . . . | . . . .
 [7,] . . . . . . | . . .
 [8,] . . . . . . . | . .
 [9,] . . . . . . . . | .
[10,] . . . . . . . . . |
```

Since I am working with big matrices, it would make my code faster. I have not found in Julia sparse matrices documentation a similar function. Is there one way to reproduce that type of matrice in Julia ?

Thanks

Julie

Answer (score 1):

You can always search Julia documentation, and also use the help mode in the Julia prompt by typing `?` followed by some keyword you are interested in. In this case, `?sparse` showed me the answer:

```
sparse([],[],[],10,10) # creates a 10x10 sparse matrix
```

Or if you want to fill some entries:

```
Is = [1;2;3]
Js = [1;2;3]
Vs = [1;2;3]

sparse(Is, Js, Vs) # creates a diagonal sparse matrix
```

Comment: It is not quite what I am looking for. The first line you wrote creates an empty sparse matrix, which I don't want. I specified I want to be able to tell Julia that there is some non zeros location but without filling them with a number, exactly like the R matrix I displayed in my question. So that for instance if I multiply that matrix by 2 it's going to display 2 on the locations I specified as non-empty.

(BTW of course I know I can type ?sparse in Julia, and I asked the question because it did not helped. I've RTFM)

Comment: So the R version does not reserve memory for the non-empty locations? The second version I wrote allows your to initialize with ones as you wish to multiply by two later. I don't understand your concerns.

Comment: The R version does, but it takes less storage space than if it was to store numbers. And it takes less time to generate. And computations are faster. Those are my concerns (stated in my question).

Comment: If you are experiencing performance differences, please let the Julia core dev team know by opening an issue on GitHub. I can't see how R stores less memory if it has to write the same numbers at some point. Maybe you are talking about initialization, in which case the first version I wrote above creates a 10x10 without initializing the elements. Also make sure you are benchmarking with BenchmarkTools when you open the issue.